# Factoring a quartic polynomial over the integers with roots that are not integers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

The quartic polynomial
$$
1728(x - 3) - x^2(12^2 - x^2)
$$
factors "nicely" as
$$
(x^2 - 12x + 72) (x^2 + 12x - 72) = (x^2 - 12x + 72)(x - 6\sqrt{3} + 6)(x + 6\sqrt{3} + 6) \, .
$$

(Note that $1728 = 3(24^2)$.)  How is this factorization obtained?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
1728(x - 3) - x^2(12^2 - x^2) & = x^4 - 144 x^2 + 1728 x - 5184 \\
 & = x^4 - 12^2 x^2 + 12 \cdot 12^2 x - 36 \cdot 12^2 \\
 & = x^4 - 12^2(x^2 - 2 \cdot 6 \,x + 6^2) = \\
 & = x^4 - 12^2(x-6)^2 = \\
 & = \big(x^2 - 12(x-6) \big)\big(x^2 + 12(x-6)\big) = \cdots
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thanks for providing a clear explanation, again.

Comment: Another member offered an explanation.  I think that she used the factorization of the given quartic polynomial into a product of two quadratic polynomials that I provided in the post.  When I asked her how she would get that factorization, she said to take compare the coefficients in the product (x^{2} + ax + b)(x^{2} + cx + d) with the coefficients in the given quartic polynomial.  Would that allow $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ to be evaluated?

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire `Would that allow a, b, c, and d to be evaluated` Yes, his comment uses the method of undetermined coefficients, and the equations you wrote down are correct. The next step is to eliminate $b,d$ between the three remaining equations, which gives a cubic in $a^2$ namely $a^6 - 2\cdot 12^2 a^4+2 \cdot 12^4 a^2 - 12^6=0\,$ with the (somewhat) obvious root $a^2=12^2$ i.e. $a=\pm 12$.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$
(x^2-12x+72)(x^2+12x-72)=x^4 - 144x^2 + 1728x - 5184=x^2(x^2-12^2)+1728(x-3),
$$
The factorization is of the form $(a^2+b)(a^2-b)=a^4-b^2$, with $a=x$ and $b=12x-72$.

Comment: If I had not provided the factorization in the post and if I had only given the quartic polynomial $1728(x - 3) - x^2(12^2 - x^2)$ to be factored, what would you do?

Comment: I would multiply it out, then look for rational roots using the rational root test, and then write my polynomial as $(x^2+ax+b)(x^2+cx+d)$, compare coefficients - and obtain a positive result!

Comment: If you are saying that $x^{4} - 12^{2}x^{2} + 12^{3}x - 3(12^{3}) = (x^{2} + ax + b)(x^{2} + cx + d)$, ...

Comment: I got $c = -a$, and so, $-a^{2} + b  + d = -12^{2}$, $a(d - b) = 12^{3}$, and $bd = -3(12^{3})$.

Comment: How would you get the values of $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ from these equalities?

Answer (score 1):

This solution was suggested by dxiv.

Solution

The given quartic polynomial factors into a product of two monic, quadratic polynomials:
\begin{equation*}
x^{4} - 144x^{2} + 1728x - 5184 = (x^{2} + ax + b)(x^{2} + cx + d) ;
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
(x^{2} + ax + b)(x^{2} + cx + d) = x^{4} + (a + c)x^{3} + (ac + b + d)x^{2} + (ad + bc)x + bd .
\end{equation*}
Since $c = -a$,
\begin{equation*}
d - b = \dfrac{12^{3}}{a}
\qquad \text{and} \qquad
b + d = a^{2} - 12^{2}
.
\end{equation*}
So,
\begin{equation*}
b = \frac{1}{2a} \Bigl(-12^{3} - 12^{2}a + a^{3} \Bigr)
\qquad \text{and} \qquad 
d = \frac{1}{2a} \Bigl( 12^{3} - 12^{2}a + a^{3} \Bigr) . 
\end{equation*}
Moreover, since $bd = -5184 = -3(12^{3})$, and
\begin{equation*}
bd = \frac{1}{4a^{2}} \Bigl(a^{6} - 2(12^{2}) a^{4} + 12^{4} a^{2} - 12^{6}\Bigr) ,
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
a^{6} - 2(12^{2}) a^{4} + 2(12^{4}) a^{2} - 12^{6} = 0 .
\end{equation*}
$\pm12$ are roots of this polynomial equation in the variable $a$. If $a = 12$, $b = -72$, $c = -12$, and $d = 72$; if $a = -12$, $b = 72$, $c = 12$, and $d = -72$. In either case,
\begin{align*}
&x^{4} - 144x^{2} + 1728x - 5184 \\
&\qquad = (x^{2} + 12x - 72)(x^{2} - 12x + 72) \\
&\qquad = \bigl(x - 6\sqrt{3} + 6\bigr)\bigl(x + 6\sqrt{3} + 6\bigr)(x^{2} - 12x + 72) .
\end{align*}